# DocuSign: Following How to request a signature by email. Multiple methods missing

Tags: docusignapi

Using .Net Core 3.1. Putting the code they have provided into an empty class and have installed the eSign NuGet package `DocuSign.eSign.dll`.

`RequestItemsService` and `Config.docPdf` do not exist in the current context.

I am a junior developer and have never used DocuSign before, so forgive me if I am missing something obvious, The documentation doesn't say anything about this from what I have read.

[DocuSign Tutorial with code examples I used.](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem. Sorry you are running into issues.
I suggest you consider using [DocuSign quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart) and get a customized C# zip file with everything ready for you to run.
Then you can just find out the code you need inside and take it from there.
The code you need is also in [GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/eSignature/Controllers/Eg002SigningViaEmailController.cs) and you can get it from there directly.